# Constrained optimization and level curves

Tags: optimization, constraints

I'm currently working on this Optimization problem:

$\min \max (|x-2|,|y+1|)$

Subject to

$x,y\geq0$

We have been asked to show the optimal solutions graphically using the fact:

$\max (|x-2|,|y+1|) = ||\boldsymbol m-\boldsymbol c||_\infty$

How do I draw level curves from $z = ||\boldsymbol m-\boldsymbol c||_\infty$ for different values of z?

Also, let's say $z=\max (|x-2|,|y+1|)$ if I was to generate the objective function:

$\min z$

How would I extract the matrix $c^T$ that comes from the standard form:

$\min c^T \boldsymbol x$

Comment: It doesn't answer your question directly, but might come in handy if you want to optimize non-smooth problems: the trick is to solve a smooth reformulation by introducing additional variables.

Let $u = |x - 2| = \max(x-2, -(x-2))$, $v = |y + 1| = \max(y+1, -(y+1))$ and $w = \max(u, v)$. We want to solve the problem:  
$\min w$  
subject to:  
$u \ge x - 2$,  
$u \ge -(x-2)$,  
$v \ge y + 1$,  
$v \ge -(y+1)$,  
$w \ge u$,  
$w \ge v$,  
$x, y \ge 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows a plot for $\max\left(|x-2|,|y+1|\right)$

[image]

as well as the correspondent level curves

[image]

EDIT

Attached the plotting script. (in MATHEMATICA)

```
Plot3D[Max[Abs[x - 2], Abs[y + 1]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5],Specularity[White, 30]]]
gr1 = ContourPlot[Max[Abs[x - 2], Abs[y + 1]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Contours -> 15, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Black];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[{1, 0} + t {-1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
gr3 = ParametricPlot[{3, 0} + t {1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3]
```

Comment: Oh cool! How did you draw those? I'd very much like to know for future visualisations!

Comment: Included de plotting script as required.